# How to change the default program used to open .html files

Tags: html, windows

I opened a notepad and typed some html tags and saved it with .html extension. But to view that in a browser I need to right click and select Internet Explorer from the list. What should I do to make that change as soon as I give .html to browser format?

Comment: Windows? Do you have "show extensions for know file types" activated? If you don't know what that is it counts as a "No". You probably created a `something.html.txt` file

Comment: This question is not about programming! Anyway, you must click Open With and select the small checkbox on the bottom to enable always opening html with the selected program. If it doesnt renders the tags well, then perhaps you had the problem specified above!

Comment: The question is marginally related to programming. @David I doubt that is the problem. HTML files usually have an application associated.

Comment: I am adding a comment since it is not programming related, Right click on the file and use the "Open with" option. The select "choose program". Select IE in the dialog box. Also, check the checkbox "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file"

Comment: +1 Alin exactly The thing I want to say .. its not a PROBLEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click->Open with.

Then choose your program (IE), and note the little *Always use this program....* checkbox at the bottom.

Don't forget to click **OK**.

Comment: As per your guidance I did. Though it opens in browser, the icon has not changed.What could be the issue?

Comment: @Sumithra See my answer... You probably set IE as the default application for `.txt` files by doing what the other answerers so eagerly suggested.

Comment: its not issue .. don't bother about the icon @ sumithra

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking to do is set the default program for opening filetype '.html'

Right click, and do 'Open With'.  Find the browser you want to open .html files with, but before clicking OK, check 'Always use this program to open this type of file'

From then on, you can just double-click your .html file and they will open in your browser.